# Continuous form date filter

Tags: vba, date, datetime, ms-access, continuous-forms

I'm trying to filter a continuous form by a range of dates using start date and end date text boxes. My code just filters everything out even though I have records that should fit the criteria. A potential issue I've noticed (but am unaware of how to resolve) is that my text boxes are formatted "MM/DD/YYYY" and my table field is a datetime format.

```
Dim datFrom As Date, datTo As Date

datFrom = txtFrom.Value
datTo = txtTo.Value
Debug.Print datFrom
Debug.Print datTo
DoCmd.SetFilter wherecondition:="expFrom BETWEEN #" & datFrom & "# AND #" &   datTo & "#"
```

Comment: Does `Debug.Print Format(datFrom, "mmm d yyyy")` show you the date you expect?  And if you do the same for `datTo`?

Comment: Good.  Now try formatting those date values like this when you include them in the wherecondition string: `"expFrom BETWEEN #" & Format(datFrom, "yyyy-m-d") & "# AND #" & Format(datTo, "yyyy-m-d") & "#"`

Comment: It's the same result as before.

Comment: Is your continuous form a subform to a main form containing the textboxes?

Comment: No, the textboxes are in the header of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though the field was originally a date field Access was switching it to a text field so I had to convert it back to a date.

```
DoCmd.SetFilter wherecondition:="CDate(expFrom) BETWEEN #" & Format(datFrom, "yyyy-m-d") & _
"# AND #" & Format(datTo, "yyyy-m-d") & "#"
```